# Significance of arrows symbols in duplicating/closing file descriptors under bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection, file-descriptors

I'm reading a book about Linux command line where author doesn't seem to follow the conventions in bash manual regarding arrows symbols used in redirection operations. Namely, he always uses left arrow `<` in duplicating and closing file descriptors regardless of whether the descriptors are input or output ones.

Here is an example:

```
exec 3<&0 4<&1 #shouldn't be 4>&1 ?
#...
exec 3<&- 4<&- #shouldn't be 4>&- ?
```

Bash man page is vague in this point, according to it, the duplicating/closing and moving file descriptors have the following syntaxes:

```
#Duplicating and closing (in case word expands to -):
[n]<&word 
[n]>&word

#Moving:
[n]<&digit-
[n]>&digit-
```

They are described to have different behaviour only if we don't explicitly supply the `n`. But when we do, does it mean that we can use these forms interchangeably?

Comment: Shouldn"t it be `4>&1`? Check http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/x13082.html

Comment: Right, my bad. However, the link doesn't answer my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter because both `4>&1` and `4<&1` do the same thing: `dup2(1, 4)` which is the system call to duplicate a fd onto another. The duplicated fd automatically inherits the I/O direction of the original fd. (same for `4>&-` vs `4<&-` which both resolve to `close(4)`, and `4>&1-` which is the `dup2(1, 4)` followed by `close(1)`).

However, the `4<&1` syntax is confusing unless for some reason the fd 1 was explicitly open for reading (which would be even more confusing), so in my mind should be avoided.

The duplicated `fd` shares the same *open file description* which means they share the same offset in the file (for those file types where it makes sense) and same associated flags (I/O redirection/opening mode, O_APPEND and so on).

On Linux, there's another way to *duplicate* a `fd` (which is not really a duplication) and create a new *open file description* for the same resource but with possibly different flags.

```
exec 3> /dev/fd/4
```

While on Solaris and probably most other Unices, that is more or less equivalent to `dup2(4, 3)`, on Linux, that opens the same resource as that pointed to by the fd 4 from scratch.

That is an important difference, because for instance, for a regular file, the offset of fd 3 will be 0 (the beginning of the file) and the file will be truncated (which is why for instance on Linux you need to write `tee -a /dev/stderr` instead of `tee /dev/stderr`).

And the I/O mode can be different.

Interestingly, if fd 4 pointed to the reading end of a pipe, then fd 3 now points to the writing end (`/dev/fd/3` behaves like a *named pipe*):

```
$ echo a+a | { echo a-a > /dev/fd/0; tr a b; }
b+b
b-b

$ echo a+a | { echo a-a >&0; tr a b; }
bash: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor
b+b
```